# how can we take objects address as element type in map

Tags: c++, dictionary

I want to take a map in which key type will be an integer and element type is an object's address. 
I write like this:

```
map<int, CEmployee*> m;
```

and adding like this:

```
m.insert(pair<int, CEmployee*>(1, new CEmployee));
```

It is giving error.

Can anybody help me out.

Thank You

Comment: what *error* does it give?

Comment: Consider using a smart pointer to prevent memory leak woes.

Comment: The 2 lines of code you put in here seem correct so you'll need to be more specific about your error if you want anybody to guess what's going on in your program ...

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/T00pJk). Please post the error, and enough code to reproduce it.

Comment: I am writing these two lines outside of the class as global. Error says: "This Declaration has no storage class or type specifier"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 m.insert(pair<int, CEmployee*>(1, new CEmployee));
```

You cannot have code like that in the global scope. It has to be within a function (regular, member, constructor, template...).